# Parse: Query to change labels text

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I can currently query a parse class, but can't figure out how to change a labels text if the returned values match the query. I am relatively new to objective C and Parse so my knowledge on the subject is little. My query looks like this (with the text of what i'm trying to achieve underneath).

```
PFQuery *FTQ0 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class1"];
[FTQ0 whereKey:@"Location" equalTo:@"The Shop"];

//Label.text = query (object?)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class1"];
[query whereKey:@"Location" equalTo:@"The Shop"];

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error && object) {
        // Do your stuff
        Label.text = [[object objectForKey:@"YOUR KEY"] stringValue];
    } else {
        // Error or null object
    }
}];
```

In this example the query return only the first object.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. You have to be careful though, because there might be many objects that have key `Location` and equal to `The Shop`. This is why parse is returning an array of objects. In this case, I pick the first object in the array and display it.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Class1"];
[query whereKey:@"Location" equalTo:@"The Shop"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

      if (!error) {

          Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[objects firstObject] objectForKey:@"WHATEVER YOU WANT TO DISPLAY EX. NAME, LOCATION..."]]
      } else {
          // Log details of the failure
          NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
      }
}];
```

For more information please visit https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your quick and helpful response! This was an issue that was troubling me allot! The code provided works!

Thanks!